# "An error occurred opening snapshot" Process Monitor

Tags: events, snapshot, sysinternals, systemevent, process-monitor

Each time I run a new instance of the Process Monitor, a dialog box pops up stating that "An error occurred opening snapshot", this error prevents the  capturing of any events.
Pressing the capture button or Ctrl+E reproduces the error message as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to resolve this error you need to clear the Logfile registry key entry.

1. Close all instances of Process Monitor.
2. Open Regedit.
3. Find the Logfile registry entry located under

   For 64 bit version:
   **HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/SysInternals/ProcessMonitor/**
   For 32 bit version:
   **KEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/SysInternals/ProcessMonitor32/**
4. Locate the key named **'Logfile'**.
5. Right click on the key and
   select 'Modify'.
6. Set the Value data to an empty string and click 'OK'.
7. Launch Process Monitor - the issue should be resolved.